# Initialize std::array at compile time when element's member is const. Custom to_array implementation

Tags: c++, c++20

At compile time I would like to create a static array from another `constexpr` static array.

My below attempt would work if only the members of the array element's type were not `const`.

```
new_foo_arr[idx] = Foo{
error: use of deleted function 'Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&&)'
```

The error is reasonable but `std::to_array` can create const elements somehow. Answers I've found on initializing the array were using lambdas but that wouldn't make any difference here.

```cpp
struct FooConfig {
    const std::string_view name;
};

struct Foo {
    const std::string_view name;
    const unsigned index;
    void* owner;
};

inline constexpr std::array foo_config = std::to_array<const FooConfig>(
        {{ .name = "A", },
         { .name = "B", },
         { .name = "C", },});

template<const decltype(foo_config)& arr>
consteval auto make_foo_array()
{
    std::array<Foo, arr.size()> new_foo_arr{};
    for (auto idx = 0u; idx < arr.size(); ++idx)
    {
        auto cfg = arr[idx];
        new_foo_arr[idx] = Foo{
                .name = std::string_view(cfg.name),
                .index = idx,
                .owner = nullptr,
        };
    }
    return new_foo_arr;
}

inline auto foo_array = make_foo_array<foo_config>();
```

Is there any way to cheat on the compiler? The `new_foo_array` is temporary anyway, so why is there so much resistance?

Comment: Why do the members need to be const? It's usually not a good idea.

Comment: @AspectOfTheNoob I've made them const to make the array a simple aggregate with sanity restrictions, which eventually led to overcomplicated initialization metaprogramming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to assign values after default-construct `Foo` array with `const` member, you can use `index_sequence` to construct `Foo` array directly:

```
template<const decltype(foo_config)& arr>
consteval auto make_foo_array()
{
  return []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array{
      Foo{.name = std::string_view(arr[Is].name), .index = Is, .owner = nullptr}...};
  }(std::make_index_sequence<arr.size()>{});
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3x7K77M96)

Answer (score 2):

Based on `foo_array` not being `constinit` / `const` and `Foo::name` and `Foo::index` being `const`, but `Foo::owner` not being `const` i'm going to assume that you want to modify `Foo::owner` during runtime, while ensuring that `foo_array` gets constant-initialized.

---

Given that the `Foo`'s within `new_foo_arr` are not complete-const objects, we can use [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at) + [`std::construct_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/construct_at) to [transparently replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) a `Foo` object within the array:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5f7fhbdjW)

```cpp
template<const decltype(foo_config)& arr>
consteval auto make_foo_array()
{
    std::array<Foo, arr.size()> new_foo_arr{};
    for (auto idx = 0u; idx < arr.size(); ++idx)
    {
        auto cfg = arr[idx];
        std::destroy_at(&new_foo_arr[idx]);
        std::construct_at(&new_foo_arr[idx], Foo{
                .name = std::string_view(cfg.name),
                .index = idx,
                .owner = nullptr
        });
    }
    return new_foo_arr;
}
```

It's not pretty, but it'll work.

---

Note that due to`foo_array` not being const it would also be legal to replace the `Foo`'s within `foo_array` at runtime, utilizing the same technique:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5vEhrnEK8)

```cpp
int main() {
   std::destroy_at(&foo_array[0]);
   std::construct_at(&foo_array[0], Foo{
       .name = "foo",
       .index = 1,
       .owner = nullptr
   });
}
```

---

If you want `Foo::name` and `Foo::index` to be truly immutable and prevent shenanigans like the above example the easiest solution would be to make `foo_array` `const` and `Foo::owner` `mutable`, e.g.:

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qo7aWqnh1)

```cpp
struct FooConfig {
    const std::string_view name;
};

struct Foo {
    std::string_view name;
    unsigned index;
    mutable void* owner;
};

inline constexpr std::array foo_config = std::to_array<const FooConfig>(
        {{ .name = "A", },
         { .name = "B", },
         { .name = "C", },});

template<const decltype(foo_config)& arr>
consteval auto make_foo_array()
{
    std::array<Foo, arr.size()> new_foo_arr{};
    for (auto idx = 0u; idx < arr.size(); ++idx)
    {
        auto cfg = arr[idx];
        new_foo_arr[idx] = {
            .name = std::string_view(cfg.name),
            .index = idx,
            .owner = nullptr,
        };
    }
    return new_foo_arr;
}

inline constinit const auto foo_array = make_foo_array<foo_config>();
```

Now that `foo_array` is `const` it would be impossible to transparently replace a `Foo` member within it.

```cpp
int main() {
   // this is now UB:
   std::destroy_at(&foo_array[0]);
   std::construct_at(&foo_array[0], Foo{
       .name = "foo",
       .index = 1,
       .owner = nullptr
   });

   std::cout << foo_array[0].name << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add back in the copy assignment operator which is automatically deleted when an object has const member objects. Note that this might not be future proof as the default copy ctor may be removed in future c++ versions (> c++23). And defining the copy ctor as default prevents the class from being an aggregate. One advantage of this approach is that the objects can be put in a vector and manipulated, eg: sorting them. They behave like any normal aggregate but provide const correctness for users.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

struct FooConfig {
    const std::string_view name;
};

struct Foo {
    const std::string_view name;
    const unsigned index;
    void* owner;

    // This special member function must be added back in
    constexpr Foo& operator=(const Foo& arg) {
        if (this == &arg)
            return *this;
         std::destroy_at(this);
        std::construct_at(this, arg);
        return *this;
    }
};

inline constexpr std::array foo_config = std::to_array<const FooConfig>(
    { {.name = "A", },
     {.name = "B", },
     {.name = "C", }, });

template<const decltype(foo_config)& arr>
consteval auto make_foo_array()
{
    std::array<Foo, arr.size()> new_foo_arr{};
    for (auto idx = 0u; idx < arr.size(); ++idx)
    {
        auto cfg = arr[idx];
        new_foo_arr[idx] = Foo{
                .name = std::string_view(cfg.name),
                .index = idx,
                .owner = nullptr,
        };
    }
    return new_foo_arr;
}

inline auto foo_array = make_foo_array<foo_config>();

int main()
{
}
```